# Java 8 Streams - summing multiple values in a type from a stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to sum the sum of two variables within a class which are streamed from a collection. Consider the following simple class.

```
class Widget {
    String colour;
    Double legs;
    Double arms;
    // ...
}
```

I want to stream a collection of Widgets, group them by colour and work out the sum of (legs + arms) to find the total number of limbs for each colour.

I want to do something simple, like this -

```
widgets.stream().collect(groupingBy(Widget::getColour, summingDouble(legs + arms)));
```

However, there's no Collectors function which allows me to specify a custom value to sum.

My question is: Do I need to write a custom Collector or is there another easy way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Collectors.summingDouble()`:

```
Map<String, Double> result = widgets.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Widget::getColour,
                Collectors.summingDouble(w -> w.getArms() + w.getLegs())
        ));
```

You can just use the function `w -> w.getArms() + w.getLegs()` to sum the arms and legs.

Answer (score 3):

You shall alternatively use `toMap` here as:

```
Map<String, Double> colorToLimbsCount = widgets.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Widget::getColour,
                widget -> widget.getArms() + widget.getLegs(), Double::sum));
```

in the `groupingBy` representation, it could look like:

```
Map<String, Double> colorToLimbsCount = widgets.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Widget::getColour,
                Collectors.reducing((double) 0,
                        widget -> widget.getArms() + widget.getLegs(), Double::sum)));
```

Comment: You can just use `0d` instead of casting an `int` with  `(double) 0`.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp or just `0.0`